# Could not load type error while publishing ASP.net Site

Tags: asp.net

I recently encountered an error for a certain web page that says "Could not load type ". I was solving this for the past weeks or so to no avail. It was working properly on my local PC but when I try to move it to the server via Tortoise SVN, it gives out that error. Any help would be appreciated guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look at the full message, you should be able to see the exact type that won't load. And I suspect that the exception may have an inner exception, describing precisely what assembly cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the project output path (project properties / Build) is set to **bin** and not **bin\Release** or **bin\Debug**

For some reason IIS (VS development Server or Local IIS) always accesses the libraries from the bin directory (and won't look up for subdirectories)

Hope this helps..